# Locate elements using find_element_by_css_selector when css path is too long

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to locate elements 1. password 2. submit button

**CSS Paths from firebug :**

**for password:**

```
...textfield-1023.x-field.loginpage-email-textfield.x-form-item.x-form-item-default.x-form-type-text.x-box-item.x-field-default.x-vbox-form-item...
```

**for button**

```
...
button-1028.x-btn.loginpage-login-button.x-unselectable.x-box-item.x-toolbar-item.x-btn-default-small span#button-1028-btnWrap.x-btn-wrap.x-btn-wrap-default-small 
...
```

code:

```
e_passwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".loginpage-password-textfield")
action_passwd = ActionChains(driver)
action_passwd.move_to_element(e_passwd)
action_passwd.click(e_passwd)
action_passwd.send_keys("symbol")
action_passwd.perform()

e_submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".loginpage-login-button")
action_button = ActionChains(driver)
action_button.move_to_element(e_submit)
action_button.click(e_submit)
action_button.perform()
```

This code is able to locate and click the submit button but not able to locate password field.

Is there any other method I need to use to locate the `textfield` elements ?

Comment: Please provide the `html` for password if you can

Comment: <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="x-form-field x-form-empty-field x-form-empty-field-default x-form-text x-form-text-default  " maxlength="64" placeholder="Password" name="textfield-1024-inputEl" size="1" role="textbox" data-ref="inputEl" id="textfield-1024-inputEl" componentid="textfield-1024">

Answer (score 1):

`Firebug` is a great tool. But does not give you what you need all the time. So, sometime it is helpful to know how to write selector manually. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css)
Simply use. `Css` allows you to add multiple attributes with `[]` to identify the element *uniquely*.

```
[placeholder='Password'][type='password']
```

Just another option if you want to use `xpath` with `find_element_by_xpath` you can also use the following:

```
//input[@placeholder='Password'][@type='password']
```

or

```
//input[@placeholder='Password' and @type='password']
```

as @alecxe suggested

Api doc is [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for the edit and upvote. BTW now I copy paste your name don't even try spelling :P

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely easier. Btw, should not the xpath be `//input[@placeholder='Password' and @type='password']`?

Comment: Thanks Saifur! Your solution is working perfectly.
I'm able to locate using following line also
`e_passwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type='password']")`

But i want to use **.loginpage-password-textfield** also while locating as it is not going to change further.

Comment: @Rameswar I don't see  `loginpage-password-textfield` class in the `html` you provide. How you are getting it?

Comment: if i copy the css path using firebug i'm able to see it. Not able to get the same using HTML.

Comment: @Rameswar not sure then `Firebug` is misleading you then. The `CSS` I provided is pretty static and I use something very similar for my testing as well

Comment: it is in outer division. `<div id="textfield-1024" class="x-field loginpage-password-textfield x-form-item x-form-item-default x-form-type-password x-box-item x-field-default x-vbox-form-item" style="width: 300px; right: auto; left: 15px; top: 64px; margin: 0px;">` which is displayed with css.

Comment: I guess you want to use `placeholder` then. I ran into the same situation testing my site. Not really sure if you can use the class even the id from that outer division. Probably not.