# Selecting value from autosuggestion box using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate wikipedia - search text field - using selenium webdriver.

I want to send text "kin" into it and select value "kinu" from the autopopulated list.

HTML for input box:input type="search" dir="auto" accesskey="F" autofocus="autofocus" size="20" name="search" id="searchInput" results="10" autocomplete="off" list="suggestions"

is there any way to traverse through the list by using key down event and select value "kinu" from the list?

[image]

From firebug , i can see that HTML for this field "kinu" is 
<"option value="Kinu">.[image]

so i tried finding the value using xpath 
WebElement el1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='kinu']"));
but i am not able to find it. is there any other way to get this ?

Comment: could you please edit your post, and include HTML, including the textbox, **and** the `<select>` element that you are trying to interact with?

Comment: @sircapsalot:edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You **MAY** need the driver to click the element first (auto complete box) then use the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'searchInput')]")).sendKeys("Kinu" + Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score -1):

Fastest way in my view:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys("Kinu");
```

Good code example might be found there: [Need to find element in selenium by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css)