# How to find element in selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

I want to find the element "Holiday4" in span class="fc-title". How to do it? Do i need to use css selector or do I need to use xpath?

```
<tr>

    <td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future hp-cal-selected" data-date="2016-02-14">14</td>
    <td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2016-02-15">15</td>
    <td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2016-02-16">16</td>
    <td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2016-02-17">17</td>
    <td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2016-02-18">18</td>
    <td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2016-02-19">19</td>
    <td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-02-20">20</td>

</tr>
```

```
<tr>

    <td class="fc-event-container">

        <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end holiday" style="color:65280" title="Holiday">

            <div class="fc-content">
                <span class="fc-title">Holiday4</span>
            </div>

        </a>
```

Comment: Why not just give your span an ID?

Comment: `By.className("fc-title")` will work for your simple case, but that's no use if there are multiple rows. Will there be?

Answer (score 0):

Use cssSelector

```
.fc-content [div:contains('Holiday 4')]
```

Also check this out 
[Need to find element in selenium by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css)

https://saucelabs.com/selenium/css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

If to use `Python`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://your_url.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="fc-title"][contain(text(),"Holiday 4")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Xpath,

```
//span[@class='fc-title'][.='Holiday4']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Text of "Holiday4" you can find it by the following.

Using Css Selector:

```
string str = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class='fc-title']")).Text;
```

Using XPath:

```
string str = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("tr/td/a/div/span")).Text;
```