# WebDriver: Can't locate elements using CSS Path

Tags: java, css, arraylist, path, webdriver

I'm using CSS Path to locate a list of elements.
I want to find it with webDriver and fill the inputs vith values. Please take a look at my piece of code:

```
String CSS_PATH = "#super-product-table tbody .a-center qty-td ";
List<WebElement> list;

public int clickAllLinks() {

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add(0, "1");
    data.add(1, "2");
    data.add(2, "3");

  list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(CSS_PATH));
    for (int a = 0; a<list.size(); a++) {
    String element = list.get(a).getCssValue("");
    System.out.println(element); 
    }

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        list.get(i).sendKeys(data.get(i));
    }

    return list.size();     
}
```

So it's not work for me. Please advice what I'm wrong with? Thank u

Comment: please see this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css

Comment: @bigJava - please provide you page source, where you want to locate your elements