# Type Error By.css(tagName)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the typeError or why. Basically all i'm trying to do is get the name of the current selected frame. Below is the code and error.

```
this.getCurrentFrameName = function(driver)
{
    var frames = driver.findElements(driver.By.css('frame'));
    for (var frame in frames)
    {
        if (frame.isSelected()) {
            return frame.getName;
        }
    }
};
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
at getCurrentFrameName (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\src\FrameHandler.js:21:75)
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\test\FrameHandlerTest.js:17:29)
at callFn (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:315:21)
at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:308:7)
at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
at C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:533:12
at next (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
at C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
at next (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\charles.sexton\WebstormProjects\JS-Selenium-Toolkit\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

**Edit:** I wanted to include everything inside the test and I still get the same error as before. I didn't include an expect, assert or should statement.

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var FrameHandler = require('../../JS-Selenium-Toolkit/src/FrameHandler.js');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
/** required imports for Google Chrome without setting the PATH environment variable */
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var chromePath = require('selenium-chromedriver').path;

describe('FrameHandler', function()
{
var frameHandler = new FrameHandler();

it('', function()
{
    var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromePath).build();
    chrome.setDefaultService(service);

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .build();

    driver.get('http://google.com');

    var frames = driver.findElements(driver.By.css('frame'));
    console.log(frames.length());
    for (var frame in frames)
    {
        console.log(frame.getName);
        if (frame.isSelected()) {
            console.log(frame.getName);
            return frame.getName;
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: what are you trying to reference when you type `By` on `findElements` line? maybe you want `driver.css...` although i'm not sure exactly what kind of object `driver` is.

Comment: This is my driver object;   driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
            .build();

Comment: so does this object have a `By` attribute?

Comment: Im trying to get all elements with the tag name frame. I am trying to reference a locator by using By.css();. This method can be found in the lib folder of the selenium-webdriver module.

Comment: I was just reading this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css - maybe you need to use `By.cssSelector`?

Comment: It does have an attribute and the By.css() function is static inside the by.js file in the lib folder. The attribute is const by = require('./by.js')

Comment: same error with By.cssSelector('frame')

Comment: The documentation of the By.js file has a function called tagName(). It is deprecated and it says in the doc to use By.css(tagName).

Comment: I am still relatively new to node.js, so I still have learning to do and I was stuck with this problem and don't understand why.

Comment: what if you created the driver object inside the function using the `driver` object being passed into the function.

Comment: @ewizard Please see the edit above

Comment: could it be a problem with the npm or package.json?

Comment: maybe you are using an old `selenium` package...does your package.json specify a version?

Comment: I just tried a reinstall of selenium-webdriver and same error. Im using webstorm also by jetbrains.

Comment: have you tried assigning `driver.By.css('frame')` to its own variable and then passing the variable as the parameter to `findElements`?

Comment: @CharlesSexton I am not familiar with Javascript Language binding, but I think you should try - `iframes = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('iframe'))` or 'iframes = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName('frame'))'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @amitbobade has just observed, `By` is not a property of the constructed builder object `driver`, but of the selenium-webdriver API instance `webdriver`.

(To any Java readers, that's the equivalent of trying to call `By.css()` on the WebDriver *instance* rather than the WebDriver **class**.)

So use `webdriver.By`, not `driver.By`.

You can see the difference using `console.log`. If you do that on `webdriver`, you can see the following:

```
webdriver =  { ActionSequence: [Function: ActionSequence],
  Browser: 
   { ANDROID: 'android',
     CHROME: 'chrome',
     [...]
     HTMLUNIT: 'htmlunit' },
  Builder: [Function: Builder],
  Button: { LEFT: 0, MIDDLE: 1, RIGHT: 2 },
  By: 
   [Function: name(name) {
       return By.css('*[name="' + escapeCss(name) + '"]');
     }],
  Capabilities: [Function: Capabilities],
  Capability: 
   { ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS: 'acceptSslCerts',
   [...]
```