# Appium: An element could not be located using Xpath in android hybrid apps?

Tags: android, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I trying to automate a hybrid app using the appium.i had developed my app using Ionic Framework. i had completed the total setup ready.then i tried to find the elements inspecting using firebug in Mozilla.i found the xpath of a particular button is   `//Button[text()='BROWSE MENU']`.

but when i try to test it using appium it is unable to find it , my test got failed.

### i tried some thing like this in my test

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='BROWSE MENU']")).click();
```

### this is the error i am getting on the console

```
FAILED: Loginforsample
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5.13 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

this is inspector[image]

i didn't know where exactly i am going wrong. initially i tried WEB_VIEW to inspect in chrome then i noticed that ionic has an advantage of direct inspecting using *ionic serve*. so i simply shifted to that and again i got struct here. please help me guys to this issue for me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show `HTML` of target button

Comment: thanks for reply,u mean html inpectctor. showing button

Comment: I mean exact `HTML` code sample for mentioned element, e.g. `<button>BROWSE MENU</button>`...

Comment: i updated my code Mr.Andersson

Comment: Could you check whether your button located inside an `iframe` element?

Comment: You mean `yeah`- you checked or `yeah`- it is in `iframe`? :)

Comment: it is in iframe

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: this is the actual xpath i getting through inspect       html/body/ion-nav-view/ion-side-menus/ion-side-menu-content/ion-nav-view/ion-view/ion-content/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/button .                this is so length so i modified it.is this cause any problem

Comment: No, seem that there is no `iframe` in button's ancestors

Comment: yes i noticed that. i check in wrong way.there is no iframe for buttons

Comment: does my current answer still lead to exception?

Comment: yes mr andersson. i am seeing the same error previously i got

Comment: any other solution

Comment: Your `XPath` seem to be ok, but there is no information in exception log about element that actually makes code fails. My code should generate `TimeoutException`, but not `NoSuchElementException`. Seems that your code fails to find another element as you said that error still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to have this problem so i have used `cssSelector` it's a good way for testing hybrid apps !

Comment: hi Emma. how to access cssSelector . will provoide an example.i actually new to selenium web drivers.

Comment: try this example ! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css

Comment: i will try it.  
 can u say how to set setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled to true in ionic framework.to switch to web_view

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `Explicit wait` to your code:

```
//driver.switchTo().frame("put_iframe_id_or_name_here");  //to switch to iframe
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[text()='BROWSE MENU']")));
element.click();
//driver.switchTo().defaultContent();  //to switch back if required
```

Comment: hey mr Andersson can u say how to set setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled to true in ionic framework.to switch to web_view

Comment: Sorry, have no idea about how `ionic` framework works :( `css selector` for your button could be `button.button.button-raised-button-balanced.ink-dark.button-block`

Answer (score 1):

just try to apply 10 seconds wait [Thread.sleep(10000);] before you are performing the operation on this button.
if it works then fine otherwise change the locator to cssSelector.