# How to located selenium element by css selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to locate an element in selenium using css selector, and I use the program "copy css selector" and got:

```
div>button[type ="submit"]
```

Is this correct?

```
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
```

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more information. What language and libraries are you using? Python? JS? Java? what versions? I assume the "copy css selector" is in Chrome or some similar browser. I'm pretty sure stackoverflow quality police are going to mark your question as lacking research, so do a bit of search in stackoverflow and you should find the answer. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css
You may find if there is more than one button on your page you may get more than one match for "submit" though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) below:

```
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
```

is syntactically correct. But as per the *copy css selector* it should have been:

```
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div > button[type='submit']")
```

---

> **Note**: [`find_element_by_*`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead

Accordingly you can also use:

```
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit']")
```

As per *copy css selector*:

```
submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > button[type='submit']")
```