# Accessing element in web page using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to be able to scrape the description on this page: [https://www.centris.ca/fr/condo-appartement~a-louer~brossard/17307615?view=Summary&uc=6](https://www.centris.ca/fr/condo-appartement%7Ea-louer%7Ebrossard/17307615?view=Summary&uc=6)

With this selector (which I copied from Chrome's inspector), Idon't get an error but an empty string. Any idea what "by" method I could use to access it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium_stealth import stealth

# Selenium setup
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(300)

stealth(browser,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True)

url = 'https://www.centris.ca/fr/condo-appartement~a-louer~brossard/17307615?view=Summary&uc=6'
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
browser.maximize_window()

# Extract necessary information
url = browser.current_url
print("URL:", url)

descr = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#overview > div.grid_3 > div.row.description-row > div.property-description.col-md-6 > div:nth-child(2)').text

print(descr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it happened because consent popup is shown on load.
When consent is shown, you description element is not visible (overlapped), so you can't get it's text.

Also I suggest to use shorter css selector `[itemprop=description]` to locate your element.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.centris.ca/fr/condo-appartement~a-louer~brossard/17307615?view=Summary&uc=6'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = driver.current_url
print("URL:", url)

consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'didomi-notice-agree-button')))
consent.click()
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(consent))

description = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[itemprop=description]')))

print(description.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the CSS selector...

```
#overview > div.grid_3 > div.row.description-row > div.property-description.col-md-6 > div:nth-child(2)
```

I would suggest you to read these answers.

- [How to located selenium element by css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657539/how-to-located-selenium-element-by-css-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Use `By.XPATH` as in:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "Bienvenue dans ce superbe grand condo flambant neuf")]')
```

Comment: Oh no, sorry I wasn't clear. I need to access the description, on any similar pages, not this specific text. I'll edit my question.